# how many members download the app from App Store

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

Am new to iOS, 
successfully I can submit the app to app store but I want know how many members are dowloaded my app, I connect to iTunes and searched into the sales and trends am not understand where I have to get installation/download
in google play store showing the download count ,

[image]

where I can get the download/installation count in iOS

pls help me ....!

Comment: in google play store that show android downloaded app

Comment: not show ios app download

Comment: reference purpose I can show like is it possible in iOS

Comment: you can show that in ituns  in app analytics

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Login to itunesconnect.apple.com.
2. Tap on 'App Analytics'.
3. Select your app from the list.
4. On the top menu bar, select 'Metrics'.
5. On the side menu bar, select 'Installations'.

Comment: @ Basheer one question in side my analytics one app showing Not Enough Data

Comment: iTunes has minimum required threshold to show in analytics. I guess your app haven't got that much information. Try to check later after some days.

Comment: I can recently upload that app in app store so I have wait for some days

Comment: yes...  give some time for apple to refresh the statistics :)

Comment: @naga no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Only owner of the application can see total downloads of the application. Third person can't able to see total downloads of the application.

Also you can find total download with the below path. 
1. Login to itunesconnect.apple.com 
2. Click on "Sales and Trends" 
3. Select "Range" for lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

**How To Check Download Count 
AppStore**

Goto: **https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/login**[image: loginpage]
Click on : **Sales and Trends**[image: mainmenu]
Click : **Units** from the left tab
Change Filter : Click date and change to **range:lifetime**
[image]

All the best Good luck to all.
Agreed on **@shahnilay86** and **@Basheer**